# VPN software to use internet connection of remote network

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-access

Which software will allow a VPN connection to a remote network and utilize that networks internet connection?

Useful for unknown free wi-fi areas to connect to a solid connection elsewhere.

Kind of like a remote desktop connection software (e.g. Teamviewer), but you just need internet access.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Teamviewer is for remote assistance and has nothing to do with a VPN. What are you looking to accomplish?

Comment: Just trying to figure out VPN's.  Do they just create a shared folder on your machine, whereas with Teamviewer, you get a GUI of the entire remote machine?

Comment: @eych - I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a VPN is. A VPN is used to allow a computer that is not physically connected to a specific network to have access to resources on that network as if it were connected locally. This allows remote computers to access shared resources on servers or RDP to a work computer that is normally behind a firewall. I would read this - http://www.howstuffworks.com/vpn.htm - if you'd like to learn more. It's a good intro.

Comment: If I could I would vote for this question to be closed since it is almost the same as this [question](http://superuser.com/questions/260395/free-vpn-to-use-when-on-public-wifi/260397#260397)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any VPN that you choose, you'd have to ensure that all your traffic is routed over the VPN, since that is not always the default.  OpenVPN is a good free VPN solution.  Some consumer routers have PPTP VPN servers built in.

Another option is to use a SOCKS proxy.  Firefox and some other programs have support for SOCKS proxies.  You could use SSH to create a SOCKS proxy to the remote server: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/security/?p=421

Answer (score 0):

Any VPN software will do this. The built-in software on Windows, OSX and Linux is all fine.

All you need is a network to connect to. There are plenty of companies which provide this service if you don't already have a secure remote connection.